# Data missing during importing data from source to sink file in kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka, pyspark, spark-streaming

I have been using kafka to get and process streaming inputs and I have the source and sink properties as:

```
name=local-file-sink
connector.class=org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSinkConnector
tasks.max=10
file=pnrsink5.xml
topics=test

name=local-file-source
connector.class=org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSourceConnector
tasks.max=10
file=pnrtes.xml
topic=test
```

And I run the standalone as:

```
bin/connect-standalone.sh config/connect-standalone.properties config/connect-file-source.properties config/connect-file-sink.properties
```

And when I give parsed input using a java program written as:

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.BufferedWriter;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.io.FileWriter;
    import java.io.IOException;

    public class parse
     {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
      {
    int count=0,c=1,a=0;
    String file="/home/tthteg/speed_pnr/Source/Source_pnr.xml";
    String l1="</PNR>";
    String line;
    try
    {
     FileReader fileReader=new FileReader(file);
     BufferedReader bufferedReader=new BufferedReader(fileReader);
     String file="/home/tthteg/speed_pnr/Source/Source_pnr.xml";
     String l1="</PNR>";
     String line;
     try
     {
     FileReader fileReader=new FileReader(file);
     BufferedReader bufferedReader=new BufferedReader(fileReader);
     BufferedWriter bufWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("/home/tthteg/speed_pnr/kafka/pnrtes.xml"));
     try
    {
     while((line=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null)
     {
       if(c%2==0)
       {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        c=1;
   }
  if(line.contains("<PNR"))
  {
   c++;

   System.out.println(line);
   bufWriter.write(line);
   while((line=bufferedReader.readLine()).equals(l1)==false)
   {
     System.out.println(line);
     bufWriter.write(line);
      }
    bufWriter.write("</PNR>");
    bufWriter.flush();
    System.out.println("</PNR>");
     count++;
   a=count;
  }
}
     }catch(Exception e)
      {
        System.out.println(e);
       }
      bufferedReader.close();
      bufWriter.flush();
      System.out.println(a);
    }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
      System.out.println(a);
    }
    }
```

PROBLEMS:
 1.Whenever I run the java file,I have to touch the source file(echo -e >> pnrtes.xml) to get the data imported to the sink file(pnrsink5.xml)
 2.I have found some data missing at the beginning(some 4 words) in the sink file.

Thank you in advance